# Google silentSignIn retunring expired idToken

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-play-services, google-signin

Using the "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth" library we log in the user to our app, google sign in. After few days when we try to fetch a new token via `silentSiginIn()` we are receiving an expired `idToken`.

Two points to note here

- The expiry ranges from few seconds to few weeks. This means we are receiving `idToken` which has expired few even couple of weeks back. And every-time we receive this same token or such users.
- This is only noticeable for a small subset of users. May be >0.5% of our user base.

Any tips how can we debug this further, would be appreciated.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: do you have a test user which this case occurs?

Comment: This might happen if the system time is incorrect on their devices.

Comment: hey, have you managed to find a root-cause? I'm facing this issue for quite some time and I'm pulling my hair off already. No matter what I do, I get an expired idToken - even if I force the user to go through the interactive sign-in prompt again. Thanks!

Comment: We hacked the solution by forcing the sdk to expier the token using inbuilt function `GoogleAuthUtil.clearToken(context, token)`